# Excluding directories same name with glob

Tags: javascript, node.js, glob

I have directories

```
/vc-abc/something
/vc-abcd/something
/vc-abcde/something
/gb/something
```

I want ignore directories have vc-... by glob, i try regex with vc-*, vc**, vc.* but it not working.